# iPython filepath autocompletion

Tags: python, ipython

I am running iPython v0.13 on windows 7 64-bit. (`qtconsole --pylab=inline`)

When I type `%cd 'C:/Users/My Name/Downloads'` it takes me to the desired location.

When I `tab` auto-complete between directories the auto-complete fails if directories have a space in their names (as in the example).

Is there a reason for this and a solution to overcome it (besides migrating to Linux or using underscores as filename/directory name separators.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just now I have a try with ipython on my mac, auto-complete works well when dealing with space-contained directory. The ipython version I used is 0.13.1. Perhaps simple upgrade your ipython can solve.

Comment: I'm here ten years later with the same issue and it's not autocompleting on my mac.